# How to check if files in two folders are the same Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 folders that are inputs to the program

```
#!/bin/bash

mn_dir=$1
en_dir=$2

for mn_file in $mn_dir/*;
do
    for en_file in $en_dir/*;
    do
        if "$mn_file"=="$en_file"; then
            echo "$mn_file AND $en_file"
        else
            rm $en_file
        fi
    done
done
```

The program is supposed to keep iterating if the names match, if not it's supposed to delete the file that doesn't match.

But using this program I keep getting

```
./match_files.sh: line 10: /var==/var: No such file or directory
rm: /var: Read-only file system
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: add dbl-sq bkts, `if [[ $mn_file"=="$en_file" ]] ; then`.... Always check your code at https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421793/how-to-compare-two-directories-and-delete-duplicate-files/421833